# how to set up svn server on my home computer?

Tags: svn

I have VisualSVN Server and I want to create a public facing repository on my computer but I can't seem to get it right. I created the repository, disabled https, and I'm trying to access the server through either

```
svn://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/svn/repo/trunk

http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/svn/repo/trunk
```

but each case gives me an error.

In the case of svn protocol:

```
Can't connect to host 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

And in the http case:

```
OPTIONS of 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080/svn/repo': could not connect to server (http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080)
```

What am I missing?
Do I need to configure an apache server or something like that in order to be able to make the server public?

I'm running on Windows Seven, windows firewall is disabled, no other firewall is installed, except for the hardware firewall in the router, but I forwarded the ports to the router, which didn't really change much..

=(

what else can I try?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you right click and select properties for your server you might check the authentication tab to see whether you have set subversion or windows authentication. Additionally when you are viewing the repositories right-click one and Copy URL to make sure the address is what you expect.

Comment: This solved my problem. Note svn:/// did not work. http did.

Comment: @dave VisualSVN Server supports only HTTP(S). It doesn't work with "svn://" out of the box.